# using return in EF transaction .net core 2.0

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, return

I am using a similar code like this and I was wondering if using ***return*** in this context is possible/acceptable as a best practice coding.

```
public static async void Run()
{
  using (var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
  {
    [some code]
    if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return;
    [continue code]
    transaction.Commit();
  }
  catch 
  {
    transaction.Rollback();
  }
}
```

Will the transaction either commit or rollback ?

Comment: `static async void` (i.e. `void`) [isn't recommended anyway](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: It was just an example, it can be just void anyway

Comment: A transaction will only commit if `Commit` is called explicitly. But multiple access points in a method isn't recommended either because it obscures the program flow.